# Sorting an ObservableCollection of Objects by Properties in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to sort an observable collection of objects by one of their properties in Xamarin Forms.

It seems like the following code should work, but it does not. I am trying to learn as much as I can, so I am very interested why it does not. I'm certain I can copy and paste the solution somewhere, but I've yet to find an answer that explains the why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;

namespace engME
{
    public partial class YourFullNamesListPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<NameObject> _nameList {get; } = MainPage.NameList;
        public YourFullNamesListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _nameList = _nameList.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name);
            FullNamesList.ItemsSource= _nameList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all i don't think your property should be like

```
ObservableCollection<NameObject> _nameList {get; } = MainPage.NameList;
```

Since you have to made changes in it later i would suggest you have get as well as set in your property(Since you might have to use it in some other class):

```
ObservableCollection<NameObject> _nameList {get; set; } = MainPage.NameList;
```

Then to set your order you do it something like this:

```
 public YourFullNamesListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _nameList =  new ObservableCollection<NameObject>(_nameList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name));
        FullNamesList.ItemsSource= _nameList;
    }
```

Where the below is of the type `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and hence you need to convert it to an observable collection by wrapping it into one.

```
_nameList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name)
```

And then you are good to go
Revert in case of queries.

Comment: I've changed the code as you recommended : https://gist.github.com/jisaacs1207/04446de55f6d3e945e20d69c24528467

Now it no longer shows anything in my listview. Perhaps it broke the binding?
https://gist.github.com/jisaacs1207/e44fcc769389cbe5fb3f37b54e7df0fc

Comment: Okay wait let me take a look

Comment: Oh i see it now don't keep your property static remove the static keyword from your property and it should work and keep it public

Comment: Thank you. I’ll have a try in the morning and get back to you. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: There are still no names being shown in the listview, but if I remove the sorting the names display just fine. 

https://gist.github.com/jisaacs1207/36a661d790f1bb52949cc0f46883bcaa

Comment: What type is your property Name, Because I see it as a string and i don't think you can use order by on that? Do you have an integer value that could work for you here?

Comment: Yes, inside Names, the property is Name. https://gist.github.com/jisaacs1207/c5b0b5964db303e5d1d9b2107771b370

Comment: If it helps, this is the MainPage code : https://gist.github.com/jisaacs1207/411f5134db966e2d6ff02ed54fa75315

Comment: Okay gimme sometime to think and i will update my answer and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178844/discussion-between-josh-isaacs-and-g-hakim).

Comment: If i am not wrong you want the names of people to be in order of the characters in thier name! i.e. ABC , ADF, AFG ,XYZ and ABB will become ABB, ABC , ADF, AFG ,XYZ Right?

Answer (score 0):

Your _nameList is getonly, thus the following assignment wont change it at all:

```
 _nameList = ObservableCollection<NameObject>(MainPage.NameList.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name));
```